# Multiple devices mirroring Android (up to 30)

Tags: android, mirroring

I have a problem with mirroring a lot of android devices (up to 30) at the same time.
I'm developing an application and I use adb with scrcpy but I can only mirror 4 devices at the same time because then the CPU reaches its limit.
There is any setting in scrcpy to optimize the cpu at best? Or there is an application like scrcpy that allows "silent" mirroring but with better performance? (by "silent" I mean without interacting with the device)